# Angular 2 directive: Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, draggable, angular2-directives

I am following [this](http://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-drag-and-drop/) example to implement drag and drop functionality on an Angular 2 cli project. All works fine on Chrome. On IE 11 though I get exceptions when I start dragging an element.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/898860/datatransfer-setdata-type-throws-an-exception-if-type-is-anything-but-text-and-url) of Internet Explorer caused by calling `dataTransfer.setData` with anything but 'Text'. Unfortunately this example was doing exactly that and failed in IE. I have implemented a different approach - using an Angular service to track the current zone. Here is the updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BerjsyCH4cYnP4s7Hm0g?p=preview).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DragService {
  private zone: string;

  startDrag(zone: string) {
    this.zone = zone;
  }

  accepts(zone: string): boolean {
    return zone == this.zone;
  }
}
```

### Draggable

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDraggable]'
})
export class DraggableDirective {
  constructor(private dragService: DragService) {

  }

  @HostBinding('draggable')
  get draggable() {
    return true;
  }

  @Input()
  set myDraggable(options: DraggableOptions) {
    if (options) {
      this.options = options;
    }
  }

  private options: DraggableOptions = {};

  @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
  onDragStart(event) {
    const { zone = 'zone', data = {} } = this.options;

    this.dragService.startDrag(zone);

    event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}
```

### Drop Target

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDropTarget]'
})
export class DropTargetDirective {
  constructor(private dragService: DragService) {

  }

  @Input()
  set myDropTarget(options: DropTargetOptions) {
    if (options) {
      this.options = options;
    }
  }

  @Output('myDrop') drop = new EventEmitter();

  private options: DropTargetOptions = {};

  @HostListener('dragenter', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver(event) {
    const { zone = 'zone' } = this.options;

    if (this.dragService.accepts(zone)) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event) {
    const data =  JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));

    this.drop.next(data);
  }
}
```